# prevent googlebot from indexing file types in robots.txt and .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, robots.txt, googlebot

There are many Stack Overflow questions on how to prevent google bot from indexing, for instance, `txt` files. There's this:

`robots.txt`

```
User-agent: Googlebot Disallow: /*.txt$
```

`.htaccess`

```
<Files ~ "\.txt$">
     Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

However, what is the syntax for both of these when trying to prevent two types of files from being indexed? In my case - `txt` and `doc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*.txt$
Disallow: /*.doc$
```

More details at Google Webmasters: [Create a robots.txt file](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961)

---

In your .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|doc)$">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</FilesMatch>
```

More details here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html

Comment: thank you. btw why does the one I used as an example say `<files>` and yours says `<ifmodule`- what is the difference? I am using a php server

Comment: Both are Apache directives. You can see the definitions here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html